# CPP console applications exits without providing error information

Tags: c++, windows

When I compile and run the below piece of code the exe crashes yet doesn't provide information of any sort regarding why it crashed. (Seg faults etc. not reported). Here is the sample code that I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <int> values;
    int temp = values.back();
    cout << temp << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The same piece of code when compiled and run-on Linux produce a seg fault. Is there something to be configured specifically in windows to let console applications generate information regarding runtime errors?

Comment: Please do not share your code in images. You can use `code block` instead.

Comment: What's your compiler? How do you run the code? Please provide more details.

Comment: Google "win10 enable wer" to get ahead.

Comment: The problem is actually "how in windows to make console applications generate information about Access Violation errors" but the STL code given is misleading, causing people to answer STL-related questions rather than exception handling in Windows. Could have given a simpler example like "int main() {int* p = nullptr;(*p)++;}". There is an Access Violation when called from Microsoft Visulal Studio IDE in Release build, but not when running this .exe in console. .back() returns 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC on an empty vector, then reading an integer from this address gives AV. The question lacks focus.

Comment: @grizzly Thanks for the edit, I tried putting it in the code block but it got garbled and I was in a hurry so thought a photo would be the quickest way forward. Will take care of this next time.

Comment: I have also tried the Windows error reporting enable option just now, with a admin shell i did `Get-WindowsErrorReporting` which returned True yet the problem remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling [`std::vector::back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back) on an empty vector is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The compiler or runtime aren't required to emit a diagnostic. There might be a tool or sanitizer that could help depending on the compiler you're using.

Comment: You're formally correct, but I think it's not the sort of UB that would silently fail. OP's code probably dereferences a null pointer under the hood, or triggers some debug assertion - both should provide prominent error messages.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You're right, there are options like UBSan, running a debug build, running inside a debugger, etc. Still, this code is off into the weeds and I don't know if there's a single correct and portable solution.

Comment: The problem is actually "how in windows to make console applications generate information about Access Violation errors" but the STL code given is misleading, causing people to answer STL-related questions rather than exception handling in Windows. Could have given a simpler example like "int main() {int* p = nullptr;(*p)++;}". The question lacks focus.

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah I realize the problem with this code and as @MaximMasiutin mentions this might've been misleading. The weird part although is that a null de-reference did pull up an error yet this one didn't when I tried g++ on both windows and linux.

Comment: @supra That's the problem with undefined behavior,. The language doesn't specify any specific behavior so it's difficult to reason about what **should** happen. What you observed might make sense if you dig into the library implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something to be configured specifically in windows to let console applications generate information regarding runtime errors?

The problem is that `value.back()` causes undefined behavior (because your vector is empty). The effect of undefined behavior is undefined. It might result in a seg fault, but also could just exit the application.  You can't enforce a segfault for that, and not really enforce a crash.

Using static analyzers and increasing the warning level can help in certain cases. But there is no way to detect all possible errors.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I do realize the problem with the code here, my pain point was the fact that it didn't produce any errors and just exited without any message making me wonder what went wrong.

Comment: @supra that depends on how the empty state and `back()` is defined for the given implementation of the specification. It might dereference an area of the memory that could cause an exception or could dereference a memory address that by itself would be valid for the application - and therefore not causing a memory access violation - but causing undefined behavior (which could manifest in any kind of behavior). While there might be implementation-specific flags that could be activated to activate errors, there is no guarantee that such flags exist. That's why static analyzers exist.

Comment: yeah I understand the suggestion, since this was a simple script I was curious to know if there is a shorter way around to find broken things. I'll try to keep this on mind when working on larger things though.